# Calendar not displaying Free/Busy when embedded

Tags: google-calendar-api

The calendar when shared must display free/busy if it is shared as public + See only free/busy settings (see below image).

I am a gmail user, hence no domain restrictions.

The below shared calendar does have an event on 27th Sep 2021 titled **Test public event** when the same is embedded the public people dont see the Free/Busy nor the event name.

[image]

But when I choose to See all event details settings my calendar does show the event, I want to prohibit event details rather only show the Free/Busy

[image]

```html
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Asia%2FKolkata&src=Y3AxZmZrYWM3a3IyZDQ3cDRsa29kYmx2Zm9AZ3JvdXAuY2FsZW5kYXIuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbQ&color=%23B39DDB&mode=MONTH" style="border:solid 1px #777" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you checking the iFrame calendar from a browser where the same account is logged in? Have you checked on other browser or incognito mode with no accounts logged?

Comment: It makes no sense checking in same account, The above question is when its viewed in incognito. I have specified in the question *when the same is embedded the public people dont see the Free/Busy nor the event name*

Comment: Have you modified the event details setting it to busy / free and testing the public / private options?

Comment: Yes all done. Still the same issue.

Comment: Can you share more details on the reproduction steps you are using to see if I am doing something different on my tests?

Comment: Sure will send a view shortly